# Java Calendar not work as expected when set time to 0 a.m

Tags: java, time

my computer default time zone is UTC, and i write a function to formate time to 0 a.m. in GMT+8 timezone. it works well for a long time. recently i find if call this function twice, it will reduce one day time. the problem function first set time then set timeZone. if first set timeZone then set time, it will work properly. i dont know why.

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {
    private static final String DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = "GMT";
    private static final String GMT_8_TIME_ZONE = "GMT+8";

    /**
     * first set time, then set time zone
     */
    public static long formatTimeToGmt8Zero(Long time) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE));
        calendar.setTime(new Date(time));
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(GMT_8_TIME_ZONE));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    /**
     * first set time zone, then set time
     */
    public static long formatTimeToGmt8Zero2(Long time) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE));
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(GMT_8_TIME_ZONE));
        calendar.setTime(new Date(time));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long beginTime = 1695957557093L;//Fri Sep 29 2023 03:19:17 GMT+0000
        long time1 = formatTimeToGmt8Zero(beginTime);
        long time2 = formatTimeToGmt8Zero(time1);
        //formatTimeToGmt8Zero beginTime:1695957557093,time1:1695916800000,time2:1695830400000
        System.out.println("formatTimeToGmt8Zero beginTime:" + beginTime + ",time1:" + time1 + ",time2:" + time2);
        time1 = formatTimeToGmt8Zero2(beginTime);
        time2 = formatTimeToGmt8Zero2(time1);
        //formatTimeToGmt8Zero2 beginTime:1695957557093,time1:1695916800000,time2:1695916800000
        System.out.println("formatTimeToGmt8Zero2 beginTime:" + beginTime + ",time1:" + time1 + ",time2:" + time2);

    }
}
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/uKZWVT).

Comment: j.u.Calendar is obsolete. And for good reason - broken in subtle ways, a non-java-like API, names that lie (an instance represents, well, not a calendar). Use `java.time`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot all my co-workers are using  Calendar, they just copy code from old repository. i need to find the reason of bug to let then not use Calendar

Comment: `GMT+8` is an offset, not a time zone. Is there a [real time zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you have in mind?

Comment: There is probably some reason why the old, confusing and cumbersome `Calendar` class would behave like that. That struggle definitely is not worth taking. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) instead. It supplanted `Calendar` and the other old classes a decade ago. `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_695_957_557_093L) .atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT+8")) .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS) .toInstant() .toEpochMilli()` yields your desired 1 695 916 800 000. Also when you repeat the operation.

Comment: Next tip, don’t play around with millisecond counts. Use proper date-time objects. Your code will be much clearer.

Comment: *i need to find the reason of bug* The reason for the bug is that `Calendar` is too confusing to work with.

Comment: *"all my co-workers are using Calendar"* - Tell them to stop.  You can borrow my megaphone if you like.  Or ... convince your manager that it is time to start doing formal code reviews, using code quality tools on your code-base, writing testcases, and all of the other things that happen / don't happen if cowboy developers are not whipped into line.  The reason not to use `Calendar` is patently obvious.  It is buggy, obsolete and (as far as most developers are concerned) deprecated.  Irrespective of this particular bug you have run into!!  There are many references to back this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes, not `Calendar`.

```java
Instant
.ofEpochMilli( 1_695_957_557_093L )
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Manila" ) )
.toLocalDate()
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Manila" ) )
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

> 1695916800000

## Details

> GMT+8 timezone

That is an offset-from-UTC, not a time zone.

- An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind the temporal meridian of UTC.
- A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

A time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `Europe/Paris` or `America/Edmonton`.

> my computer default time zone is UTC

I strongly recommend you write your code in such a way that the default time zone is irrelevant.

FYI, the default host OS’ default time zone does not directly apply to Java. The JVM keeps [its own current default](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) time zone. That default *may* have been picked up from the host OS, but not necessarily. Any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can instantly change the JVM’s current default time zone.

> `Calendar calendar = Calendar…`

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Sun Microsystems, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those legacy classes, and so should you.

Instead use only *java.time* classes.

> 1695957557093L

I will assume this number is meant to be a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC (an offset of zero).  But you really should document the meaning of such a number to declare (a) which granularity, (b) [which epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_695_957_557_093L ) ;
```

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment as seen in UTC. It has a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), finer than your milliseconds. To generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

```
2023-09-29T03:19:17.093Z
```

If you *really* want to use a hard-coded offset of eight hours ahead of UTC, instantiate a `ZoneOffset`.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 8 ) ;
```

Apply that to our `Instant` to get an `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset ) ;
```

```
odt.toString() => 2023-09-29T11:19:17.093+08:00
```

But you really should be using a time zone rather than an offset. Politicians frequently change the offset for their jurisdiction. By using a time zone, and keeping the [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) of your JVM up-to-date, you will be soft-coding the offset, adjusting automatically per the whims of the politicians.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Manila" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

```
zdt.toString() => 2023-09-29T11:19:17.093+08:00[Asia/Manila]
```

Apparently you want the first moment of the day. But you assume the day starts at 00:00. That is not always the case. Some dates in some zones start at another time, such as 01:00. So let *java.time*  determine the first moment.

First extract [the date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

```
ld.toString() => 2023-09-29
```

Then determine the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

```
zdtStartOfDay.toString() => 2023-09-29T00:00+08:00[Asia/Manila]
```

Lastly you want to know the count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z for that moment. To do that, extract an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instantStartOfDay = zdtStartOfDay.toInstant() ;
```

```
instantStartOfDay.toString() => 2023-09-28T16:00:00Z
```

Interrogate for the count of milliseconds.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instantStartOfDay.toEpochMilli() ;
```

```
millisecondsSinceEpoch  => 1695916800000
```

By the way, I recommend you *not* track time by these count-of-milliseconds. Such a number is easily confused (granularity, epoch reference). And such a number cannot be read by humans, so otherwise obvious mistakes in values can slip by unnoticed. Instead, when storing and exchanging such date-time values, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats in text.

See all this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/D2KoZn).